# The value of the local variable isn’t used In Dart

Tags: dart

```dart
void main() {
  List Users = [
    {"Name": "Mohamed", "Age": 21, "Phone": 3303304, "password": "nerkl"},
    {"Name": "Ahmed", "Age": 34, "Phone": 2299833, "password": "bftjss"}
  ];
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I would agree that it is not used.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a warning, not an error. The compiler sees your program is if it's completely finished. Since you don't actually use `Users` yet it gives you the warning, because it means you could delete those lines and it doesn't change the behaviour of your program at all. It's normal to see this a lot while you are still developing. Once you do something with the `Users` variable the warning will go away. Like if you write a simple

```
print(Users);
```

you will notice the warning goes away. Also a small advice: The usual coding conventions are that you don't write variables with a capital letter, this is usually only done for class names. So I would change it to `users` but that is all up to you.

Answer (score -1):

The variables you declared are never used, only assigned to, therefore you're being warned.